Google Route Optimization API - how to construct header for POST request without OAuth? Need route optimization 25+ stops
My organization was using the Google Directions API for route optimization, but we migrated to the Routes API because initial documentation suggested it would allow us to optimize routes with  25+ waypoints.
Now it appears this functionality has been broken out into a separate "Route Optimization" API as of ~2 months ago. The Route Optimization API is quite new, and some of its internal documentation still throws a 404 error. I can't find an example of what the header should look like in a REST POST request for this new API.
To use the Routes API your header looks like this:
-H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
-H 'X-Goog-Api-Key: YOUR_API_KEY' \
-H 'X-Goog-FieldMask: routes.optimizedIntermediateWaypointIndex' \
'https://routes.googleapis.com/directions/v2:computeRoutes'

I couldn't find a way to do the same for the new Route Optimization API. The only documentation was for OAuth/google cloud "projects".
Do you need to use OAuth to submit POST requests to the Route Optimization API?
I already tried submitting a POST request using Routes API headers with content from the Route Optimization API documentation example and it did not work.

any luck with this

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/routes/opt-way

It appears Google has broken away the 25+ stop route optimization functionality from the Routes API into a new ‘Route Optimization API’. This new API only functions within a Google cloud project hosted on the google maps platform with OAuth enabled. @DileepaMabulage
